# Focus on input and remove focus using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tying to check if the input has focus to add color to the back ground However when I remove the mouse and focus on another input it doesn't remove the focus anymore
it actually stays with the focus! how can I remove the backgound from the first one!

```
Fullname: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
```

How can I check that the class test exists

I'm tying the following if statement by not working for some reason. it may be something wrong with my code that I can't spot for some reason!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");
    });
});
```

I would approcialte it if you can test this for me or let me know what's going wrong on the above code!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **.blur**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");
    });
    $("input").blur(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    });
});
```

Or you can add class to each part of the html code:

```
Name: <input class="name" type="text" name="fullname"><br>
Email: <input class="email" type="text" name="email">
```

And use the following JQuery code to run it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");
        $(".email").css("background-color", "#ffffff");        
    });
    $(".email").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");
        $(".name").css("background-color", "#ffffff");        
    });
});
```

Comment: I would use the ".blur" as it's more relevant to this question! but good answer!

Answer (score 1):

For better way you can use CSS:

```
input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

but with using jquery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#cccccc");
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check that if class exist on focus then do some action same on focus out.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("input").focus(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("yourclassName")){
     $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");
    }

}).focusout(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("yourclassName")){
     $(this).css("background-color", "#f4fcef");//some other color.
    }
});

});
```